# Problem Installing Python Package from Bitbucket Repository

Tags: python, git, bitbucket, python-packaging

I'm having a crazy problem installing a package I built and placed in a bitbucket repository to a local environment.

I built the package.

I was successfully able to connect to it from Pycharm locally by doing:

```
pip install -e path/to/repository
```

I then pushed the built package to bitbucket.

I then switched local environments and pip installed the package from bitbucket as follows:

```
pip install git+https://my_name@bitbucket.org/my_company/my_repo.git
```

The package successfully installed locally.

I see it in pycharm and pycharm sees it in the environment site-packages.  It looks like this:

[image]

I can't tell if it is installed properly but I note there are no .py files.

The script in this environment doesn't see the package.

I get the following error:

[image]

Any guidance on what could be wrong?  Again, everything works fine when I'm local and using `pip install -e`.  The code works.  Just can't get it to work from pushed distribution packages from a remote repository.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your `setup.py` in the base dir? Have you tried with `#egg=...`?

Comment: yes to both of those

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this counts as a true solve but got it working.  And after about 10 hours of work on this I'm not exactly sure how.  I believe the issue may boil down to a stray comma - yes a comma - in the setup file which was not enough to throw an error but somehow left the build without some necessary parameter which resulted in a bad build when trying to install from the repository.

This also raises questions for me as to how `pip install e` works.  This because my local editable install worked fine.

Very troublesome that I can't definitively identify the cause of this issue though I've seemed to resolve it.